# The derivative of 1 = (x)(1/x). Did I miss sth here?

Tags: derivatives

As 1 is x times 1/x, I think I could derive 1 to be (x)'(1/x) + (x)(1/x)' which equals to (1/x) + xlogx. So what is wrong here? Could sb tell me? Thank you!

Comment: $\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\not=\log x$, that's the antiderivative.

Comment: I made a blunder. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define $u = x$ and $v = {1 \over x}$, we use the product rule to calculate the derivative of
$$
1 = u v = x \ {1 \over x}
$$

Note that
$$
{d \over dx}(u v) = u {dv \over dx} + v {du \over dx}
= (x) \left( - {1 \over x^2} \right) + {1 \over x} (1) \tag{1}
$$

Simplifying (1), we get
$$
{d \over dx}(u v) = - {1 \over x} + {1 \over x} = 0
$$

Hence, we have shown that the derivative of $1$ is zero, when we write $1$ as $1 = x {1 \over x}$.

Comment: I made a mistake. Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you like my answer, you may upvote it - thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote since I don't have enough reputation, but I accepted your answer

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}\\
(x(1/x))'
&=(x')(1/x)+x(1/x)'\\
&=(1)(1/x)+x(-1/x^2)\\
&=(1/x)-x/x^2\\
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I made a blunder. Thank you!